# Step by step calculate score of Solr

Tags: solr

I want know solr calculated score.Example,with document 1 "i go to school",document 2 "my school is beautyfull" and query "school".Sorry for my english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the "debug=true" parameter to your query and you'll be able to see the whole explain.

If you instead simply wants to have that score returned as part of the search results you should include the "score" field in the "fl" parameter

Comment: Tks Andrea ,but i dont know some field in this,i think score= tf x idf,is it true?

Answer (score 1):

The excellent site Solr Explain http://explain.solr.pl/ will help you understand scores much faster than the default Solr output.

Comment: tks Yann,but i want to see formula step by step of solr score ,example:tf =,idf=...

Comment: Hi Thuy, the debug info suggested by Andrea will give you will give you all the info. This page http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html will help you interpret the output of the debug.

Comment: Solr Explain link broken!

Comment: The link to this explanation is broken.